# Active Collab get user info by token or credential is avalable?

Tags: activecollab

**What I have did :**

I get credential from user and generate token and stored this token in db. For making API call I use this token.It works fine.

**Now what is required**

In myapp, user can create comment and also delete comment , I want to show the delete button of comment that he owns. But in myside (myapp) how to make delete button available to current logged in user only to those comment that he owns.

Is there any API to get user info by token / email , so that I can uniquely identify user between myapp and Active Collab side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID of authenticated user is available as `logged_user_id` key in response to `/api/v1/user-session` URL. In that response you'll find a lot of user specific settings and listings.

Note that delete option is available 30 minutes after comment has been added. When that time expires, delete and edit commands will be locked, so only users with `Owner` role will be able to perform them.